# Error message when trying to create account

Tags: accounts, account-name

I've been trying to create a new account with eostoolkit.io and I keep getting the following error message.

The name I'm trying to register has not yet been claimed yet, and I have enough resources for the purchase.

Any ideas it is failing?

DETAILS: "{\"CODE\":500,\"MESSAGE\":\"INTERNAL SERVICE ERROR\",\"ERROR\":{\"CODE\":3050003,\"NAME\":\"EOSIO_ASSERT_MESSAGE_EXCEPTION\",\"WHAT\":\"EOSIO_ASSERT_MESSAGE ASSERTION FAILURE\",\"DETAILS\":[]}}"

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you connected an account in eostoolkit? You'll see 'Attach an Account' in the 'Creator' field on the create account form if you haven't. 
If not, click 'Connect Account' at the top of the dashboard.

This should be the scatter account you wish to use to create the new account. You also need enough EOS in the creator account to be able to cover the small costs for memory & fees (< .5 EOS).

You should also check the network connection in Scatter, make sure it's the EOS mainnet and check the endpoint. I've had it fail before and realized I was getting a 404 on the network connection.

I have received this error even after connecting my scatter account. After reconnecting the account and trying again, it succeeded.

Answer (score -1):

What was the name you were trying to create? You need to make sure that names are 12 characters long.

It also could be that the name you were trying to create was already taken.